# How to list a published reply to editor in publication list

Tags: publications

I recently had a reply which myself and my coauthors wrote in response to a question from a reader of our published article be sent as a letter to the editor which was published after my initial article in the journal. The reply has its own DOI number. I am wondering what the best way is to list this in my publication list. Should it be a sub-bullet point to the main article, its own bullet points, or something else?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: First time I'm hearing of replies being in a publication list. I get the rationale, but it also seems like a way to pad the list. If you must include, I'd think it should be in the same point as the main article, maybe in brackets.

Comment: Perhaps you can ask first if a reply shall be mentioned. Personally I don't know. If it is a standard way, then cite it as any other paper.

Comment: @AppliedAcademic The times I remember seeing it done, the authors wanted to directly address that there's been a critical comment, and their response to it.

Answer (score 3):

A conference paper, journal article, letter, book chapter, ..., they're all just publications, they can each appear as independent entries on your publication list. A blurb can describe relations between works, e.g., *I pioneered X [1], with extensions to Y [2] and Z [3]*, where X is your original article, Y is your letter, and Z is, I don't know your work, something else you did in that area.